# Heroku Dep Issue: SSH, PubKey Failure (Errno::EISDIR)

Tags: ruby, bash, heroku, ssh

I'm currently working through Hartl's tutorial, struggling to deploy to heroku. Running OSX 10.8.1.

Experienced ssh issues and read thru *three-dozen questions* here, but can't figure it out.
I've added two additional ssh id's but it gives me the following error for id's 2 and 3.

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: email@gmail.com  
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Found the following SSH public keys:
1) github_rsa.pub
2) id_dsa.pub
3) id_rsa.pub

Which would you like to use with your Heroku account? 3
Uploading SSH public key /Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... failed
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Is a directory - /Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Errno::EISDIR)
    Backtrace:   

  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:290:in `read'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:290:in `block in associate_key'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:236:in `action'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:288:in `associate_key'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:269:in `associate_or_generate_ssh_key'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:239:in `check_for_associated_ssh_key'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:233:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84:in `get_credentials'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41:in `login'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:31:in `login'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.32.4/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
  /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku login
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.32.4 (x86_64-darwin12.1.0) ruby/1.9.3 autoupdate
```

When I do get the id to load/authorize, I attempt to `git push heroku master` yet I'm met with:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Could the issue perhaps be that I need to replace #1 with #3 (delete all but the #3 id?)

Would love your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regenerating your public key again. But before that, try `heroku keys:add` again. Otherwise, `ssh-keygen -t rsa` then `heroku keys:add`.

But do note that if you change your keys, the the rest of the applications which you have tied your previous keys too will have to be changes also.

Comment: Thanks. I've added two more now, but not sure i did it right.
1) i presume i should delete the old keys yes? 
2) should i be in the ~/.ssh directory when i do this?

Comment: Yeah you can always delete the old keys. No you don't have to be in the ssh directory because it is assumed.